# while vs each loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I am transposing a 2D array of M rows and N columns, where M is the length of the outer array and N is the length of the nested arrays (I accounted for different lengths in my solution):

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

My working solution with `each` is:

```
(0..(@columns-1)).each do |col|
  (0..(@rows-1)).each do |row|
    print @ar[row][col]
  end
  print "\n"
end
```

and the result is:

```
136710
24-811
-5-912
```

As a result of a validation, I filled the empty spots with `'-'` to make the inner arrays the same length.

I tried to solve the problem with the following `while` loop:

```
while @columns > 0
  while @rows > 0
    p @ar[(@rows - 1)][(@columns - 1)]
    @rows = @rows - 1
  end
  @columns = @columns - 1
end
```

and the result was:

```
12
9
"-"
5
"-"
```

Why did the `each` loop work while the `while` loop didn't?

Comment: In `while` version, you do not reset `@rows` on each iteration of outer loop. Also you might be using those vars later on, but their values are corrupted now.

Comment: @TheF `@rows` and `@columns` are not arrays, it seems.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev true. Your comment is totally right.

Comment: Where are `M` and `N` used? What are `@columns` and `@rows`?

Comment: @sawa N and M were what the book names the vars, I used `@rows` and `@columns` because 1. they made more sense to me and 2. I used them in other methods which is why they're instance and not local variables.

Comment: @SoSimple: if they're used elsewhere, you shouldn't be so cavalier about changing their values in a stupid loop :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I'm beginning to realise that! To be honest I totally forgot to make sure the while loop wasn't affecting anything permanently, I'm starting to see that the `.each` loop is the way to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that after you exit your inner rows loop for the first time, `@rows` is set to 0. Since `@rows` is never reset to its original value, `@rows > 0` will still be false after you move on to the next column. Try this instead:

```
original_rows = @rows
while @columns > 0
  while @rows > 0
    print @ar[(@rows - 1)][(@columns - 1)] # Also use `print` here, not `p`
    @rows = @rows - 1
  end
  print "\n" # You also forgot this
  @columns = @columns - 1
  @rows = original_rows # Move back to the first row
end
```

Of course, in a real application the best way to transpose an array is actually just:

```
@ar.transpose
```

But that's not very helpful for a learning exercise.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, I can't think of single reason not to use local variable `rows`, when you are setting `@rows` value back in the end anyways.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP has a reason for that. He didn't provide the full code he was using, so I tried to change as little as possible while still fixing the problem. I've updated my answer with a "real-world" solution which ignores that restriction.

Comment: @Borsunho I use instance variables because I use them in other methods as well. I didn't show those methods in my question because they're mostly just validating input and not really all that relevant to the question.

Comment: @SoSimple You might want to be careful here, since the loop is changing those instance variables. If you call this method, the variables will still be changed when you later call the other methods which use these same variables.

Comment: @Ajedi  Yes I've realized that now. Really silly of me not to have seen it sooner! Thanks for your explanation though, it's really helpful. I think that I'll stick with the `.each` loop - it seems to be the more acceptable way to do things. Also yes, I knew about transpose :)

Comment: @SoSimple yes, `each` and other iterators are there exactly to eliminate possibility of errors like this - you just can not mess up `each` or  `collect`, they do what they are supposed to do no matter what.